# Add extra database command with Entity Framework CommandTree interceptor

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I am trying to implement an auditable datastore in Entity Framework. My intention is to keep a history of every record's state at any given point in time. This requires that I convert all delete statements to updates and all update statements to update + insert.

I followed the [TechEd 2014 EF6 soft delete session](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B417) video for the basic setup of the interceptor, but I have come to a point where I am not sure how to proceed. I have valid cases for query, delete, and insert, but update is the tricky one.

Here's the basic structure of the method:

```
public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
{
    if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace == DataSpace.SSpace)
    {
        //other query interceptors

        var updateCommand = interceptionContext.OriginalResult as DbUpdateCommandTree;
        if (updateCommand != null)
        {
            //I modify the command to soft delete the current record
            //(This is pseudo code to replace to verbose EF exp builder code)
            var newClause = GetNewSoftDeleteClause(updateCommand);
            interceptionContext.Result = GetUpdateCommandTree(updateCommand, newClause);

            //Here is where I want to insert a new command into the tree
            //and copy over the data to a new record
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, one can modify the current `Result` within the `TreeCreated` method, but I cannot find a way to insert a new command into the context. As the interceptor appears to only deal with a single-row operation, I am beginning to think what I want to do is not possible within the `TreeCreated` method.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want to do using interceptors without resorting to database triggers?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can overwrite the `savechanges()` in your AppicationDbContext. You can use inbuilt property `ChangeTracker` to find out object that are going to update then attach new object that need to insert.

```
 public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        List<DbEntityEntry> dbEntityEntries= ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(e => e.Entity is Person && e.State == EntityState.Modified)
                .ToList()

        foreach(var dbEntityEntrie in dbEntityEntries)
        {
             var person = (Person)addedCourse.Entity;
             var log= new Log()
               {
                   Name=person.Name;
               }
             Logs.Add(log);
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

You can refactor this code using Inheritance and Generics.